# AngularJS Directive controller inheritance

Tags: angularjs, inheritance, angularjs-directive

I have an AngularJS directive that I use in several pages, but each time a little differently. So I want to keep my global directive, then create implementations of this directive to override some functions, while still using global functions.

"Parent" directive :

```
'use strict';
angular.module('app.leaderBoardDirective')
.directive('fooLeaderBoard', LeaderBoard);

LeaderBoard.$inject = [];

function LeaderBoard(

) {

    var directive = {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: false,
        templateUrl: 'foo/leaderBoard.template.html',
        scope: {
            ***someParams***
        },
        controller: LeaderBoardDirectiveController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true
    };

    return directive;

    LeaderBoardDirectiveController.$inject = [
        ***'dependencies'***
    ];

    function LeaderBoardDirectiveController(
        ***dependencies***
    ) {

        /* A LOT OF FUNCTIONS/VARS */
    }
}
```

"Child" directive : 
This is a leaderboard, but is displayed on a room page, so it needs some
different functionalities, like a kick button on each player.

```
'use strict';
 angular.module('app.roomPage')
.directive('fooRoomLeaderBoard', RoomLeaderBoard);


RoomLeaderBoard.$inject = [];

function RoomLeaderBoard() {

    var directive = {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: false,
        templateUrl: 'foo/leaderBoard.template.html',
        scope: {
            ***same params that in the parent***
        },
        controller: RoomLeaderBoardDirectiveController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true
    };

    return directive;

    RoomLeaderBoardDirectiveController.$inject = [
        '$controller',
        '$scope'
    ];

    function RoomLeaderBoardDirectiveController(
        $controller,
        $scope
    ) {
        var vm = this;
        /* here, I tried to extend my child directive's controller 
        with the parent directive's one to access his functions and maybe 
        override some of them
        */
        angular.extend(vm, $controller('LeaderBoardDirectiveController', 
        {$scope: $scope}));
    }
}
```

Of course, I imported my directive by calling the corresponding module, but when I do the angular.extend, I got an error that say that the controller fooLeaderBoard is not registered.

Incidentally, my parent directive already use a service that communicate with an API, but I just want to avoid duplicate code.

Comment: it should be much easier to achieve your goal with [tranclusion](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude#multi-slot-transclusion) -  especially multi-slot - or composition of several directives where each one adds some functionality.

Comment: while going "composition of several directives" way you can make them communicate(to call each other's methods) by using [require](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate) feature

Comment: Example of what @skyboyer is suggesting: http://jsfiddle.net/nsisodiya/WgSch/